# Visual C++ 2013 std::string memory leak

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-leaks

During development of proprietary app. I have noticed memory leak, related to std::string in a MS Visual C++ 2013, Update 4.

Take a look at the following (basic) code prototype which causes memory leak:

```
static std::string MemoryLeakTest()
{
    static size_t const test_size = 2002;
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> result1(new char[test_size]);
    std::string result2(result1.get(), test_size);
    return result2;
}
```

calling it by:

```
std::string const testML = MemoryLeakTest();
std::cout << testML << std::endl;
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is it a memory leak in a Visual C++ STL?

P.S. this is DebugView output showing mem leak detected by VLD:

```
[11140] WARNING: Visual Leak Detector detected memory leaks!
[11140] ---------- Block 3 at 0x00A95620: 2002 bytes ----------
[11140]   Leak Hash: 0x1DA884B6, Count: 1, Total 2002 bytes
[11140]   Call Stack (TID 9568):
[11140]     0x0FF5C260 (File and line number not available): MSVCR120D.dll!operator new
[11140]     f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\stdcpp\newaop.cpp (6): TestCpp.exe!operator new[] + 0x9 bytes
[11140]     c:\work\testcpp\testcpp.cpp (307): TestCpp.exe!MemoryLeakTest + 0xA bytes
[11140]     c:\work\testcpp\testcpp.cpp (401): TestCpp.exe!wmain + 0x9 bytes
[11140]     f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\dllstuff\crtexe.c (623): TestCpp.exe!__tmainCRTStartup + 0x19 bytes
[11140]     f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\dllstuff\crtexe.c (466): TestCpp.exe!wmainCRTStartup
[11140]     0x75557C04 (File and line number not available): KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x24 bytes
[11140]     0x77C4B54F (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x8F bytes
[11140]     0x77C4B51A (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x5A bytes
[11140]   Data:
```

Comment: how you know it's std::string which causes the leak?

Comment: Your code has undefined behaviour because you are reading uninitialized values.

Comment: How did you determine that this code leaks?

Comment: @wonkorealtime: The solution was tested with Visual Leak Detector, and it reports memory allocated but unfreed block. For some reason, I cant reproduce it always. It happens just sometimes (?)

Comment: @KerrekSB: memory must be freed, regardless of its content. You can delete the example line where output is shown.

Comment: @Casey: Using Visial Leak Detector (and appropriate #include <vld.h> header)

Comment: I get no leaks from this code, using _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks as erol suggests.

Comment: @TiodorJovovic: Undefined behaviour happens at the line `std::string result2(result1.get(), test_size);`. The remainder of the program is immaterial.

Comment: @Robinson: did you try to use _CRTDBG_CHECK_CRT_DF flag in a call to _CrtSetDbgFlag() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried your code with Deleaker and it couldn't find any leak.

Then tried this code:

```
while (true)
{
    std::string const testML = MemoryLeakTest();
    std::cout << testML << std::endl;
}
```

Task Manager shows that memory usage remains the same: no leaks.

I think this is a bug in VLD, you can find that std::unique_ptr really frees the memory, just step into during debugging, look:

```
~unique_ptr() _NOEXCEPT
    {   // destroy the object
    _Delete();
    }
```

Go further:

```
void _Delete()
    {   // delete the pointer
    if (this->_Myptr != pointer())
        this->get_deleter()(this->_Myptr);
    }
};
```

Go further:

```
void operator()(_Ty *_Ptr) const _NOEXCEPT
    {   // delete a pointer
    static_assert(0 < sizeof (_Ty),
        "can't delete an incomplete type");
    delete[] _Ptr;
    }
};
```

Aha, delete[] is called!

Comment: Yes, my final conclusion is the same - it's probably a bug in a VLD. Many thanks for your time and analysis.

Answer (score 0):

The call

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> result1(new char[test_size]);
```

is correct. The tricky part is NOT to write `std::unique_ptr<char>`, which also compiles and can cause a memory leak (`unique_ptr` calls `delete` to release resource. When initialized with `new[]`, we need to instruct `unique_ptr` to call the correct `delete[]`).

The `std::string` constructor call is also OK and it's very unlikely there's a memory leak. The `std::string` can be initialized from a C-style pointer in the same way.

I don't see any memory leak in your code snippet. How do you know it's a memory leak?

Comment: That's no longer true is it?  The latest standard handles array deletion automatically in shared_ptr and unique_ptr.

Comment: @Robinson Exactly, MSDN documentation states:

 (A partial specialization unique_ptr<Type[]>manages array objects allocated with new[], and has the default deleter default_delete<Type[]>, specialized to call delete[] _Ptr.)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee410601.aspx

Comment: Still scratching my head about the difference between std::unique_ptr<char> and std::unique_ptr<char[]>.  I suppose they compile to the same thing, or is the latter effectively a pointer to a pointer?  That would make it break (but it doesn't for me).

Comment: @Robinson They both wrap a `char*`. `unique_ptr<char>` disposes of that pointer with `delete` and `unique_ptr<char[]>` disposes of it with `delete[]`.

Comment: @Robinson: Consider you have a `new char` and a `new char[]`. How do you delete each one later? Now, how must `unique_ptr` delete each one later?

Comment: I assumed unique_ptr had a template for char and for char array and that the compiler magically knew the correct delete to use.  I know it didn't used to and you had to write your own custom deleter.  I thought this had been resolved in the latest standard.